# How to deploy aiohttp websocket?

Tags: nginx, python-3.5, gunicorn, aiohttp

I'm working on a websocket with aiohttp and i works ok with the run_app method and works great with gunicorn with the following command.

> gunicorn wsredis:app --bind 0.0.0.0:1234 --worker-class
>   aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker

When i connect to the socket doing this i got this response.

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: upgrade
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Sec-Websocket-Accept: sMOPKXQxUMYzguN7KBnuJxEQqFY=
Date: Tue, 27 Jun 2017 07:53:03 GMT
Server: Python/3.5 aiohttp/1.3.3
```

The problem comes when i try to have the websocket running in the background.

So if i make

> gunicorn wsredis:app --bind 0.0.0.0:1234 --worker-class
>   aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker &

It works in the same way until i exit from the ssh session. Then i got this response from the server.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 170
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 27 Jun 2017 08:06:51 GMT
Server: Python/3.5 aiohttp/1.3.3
```

Anyone knows what i'm doing wrong?
I tried to make a reverse proxy under nginx but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

The problem was that i had some print statments inside the script so when i exited the ssh. The script cant print and raises an exception.

Solution was delete the print statements and add loggings instead